# c# windows form How received webbrowser contain ":" character full line in listbox?

Tags: regex, webbrowser-control, innerhtml, contain, htmlelements

I am want to scrapped webbroser to ":" all line.

If finding : then scrapped full line with all line from the browser area.

below code I am trying but not getting any result pls check & give me solution.

```
if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains(":"))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(webBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains(""));
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean to add the DocumentText to the listBox?

```
if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains(":"))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(webBrowser1.DocumentText);
        }
```

Comment: Or maybe he wants the line in the DocumentText that contains the :